# Manga with kids befriending an alien girl. Chapter had them celebrating Christmas

Tags: story-identification, manga

I remember reading a chapter where the characters celebrated Christmas and exchanged gifts. All of the kids were very young and the human group was a mix of boys and girls. They befriended a young alien girl and spent time on her UFO. The art was very cute and chibi-like. That’s all I can remember so far I hope someone can help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. When exactly did you read this?